# Wrong timestamp format on kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm new in kibana, currently i'm working with aws waf and i'm using kibana to visualize my waf log. but i got problem in timestamp format it's in number format instead of date format.

[image: my timestamp format sample]

i have tried to add _timestamp format, but the log didn't showed up due to wrong timestamp.
thanks.

sample log

> {"timestamp":1608166564696,"formatVersion":1,"webaclId":"arn:aws:wafv2:ap-southeast-1:regional/webacl/***/","terminatingRuleId":"Default_Action","terminatingRuleType":"REGULAR","action":"ALLOW","terminatingRuleMatchDetails":[],"httpSourceName":"ALB","httpSourceId":"-app/api-staging-waf/a4cc29fda18b3ac2","ruleGroupList":[{"ruleGroupId":"regional/rulegroup/SQLi_Prevention/a9616e2c-0c1f-4a7b-9278-8","terminatingRule":null,"nonTerminatingMatchingRules":[],"excludedRules":null}],"rateBasedRuleList":[],"nonTerminatingMatchingRules":[],"httpRequest":{"clientIp":"10.90.40.000","country":"-","headers":[{"name":"Host","value":"api.com"},{"name":"Content-Length","value":"81"},{"name":"content-type","value":"application/json"},{"name":"authorization","value":"REDACTED"},{"name":"accept-encoding","value":"gzip"},{"name":"user-agent","value":"http-client/2.0"}],"uri":"/notification/","args":"","httpVersion":"HTTP/2.0","httpMethod":"POST","requestId":"1-5fdaaca4-5d4a7a83048d7bb54ded7d0c"}}
> Blockquote

Comment: Can you show a sample log document that you're indexing?

Comment: Hi i just added sample log. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you're indexing long values as `"timestamp":1608166564696,` ES will not transform that to a formatted date inside the source document.

However, if the mapping of the `timestamp` field is correctly defined as having type `date`

```
  "timestamp": {
    "type": "date"
  }
```

Then, in the Discover view in Kibana, you'll see properly formatted dates, such as below:

[image]

Comment: HI thanks, so how can i convert from long type to date type in kibana?

Comment: You need to reindex your data into a new index that has the right mapping. You cannot change the mapping type from long to date once the index has been created